# Why Ether wallet address changed after reinstalling windows

Tags: metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I'm having some issue to understand what is happening with my account if somebody can help me out or guide me how to fix it please.

So what happened is that after reinstalling my windows on my laptop and reinstalling chrome and downloading Metamask(directly from Metamask.io) and following the existing account where I added my 24 words recovery phrase, is opening a new account with a different wallet address..
So on my existing wallet address was starting with 0xaa43.. and after had changed to 0x288.. , after a closer look on Etherscan.io checking my initial account starting with 0xaa43..  all my amount and transactions is untouched making me to believe that I wasn`t stolen or hacked.

What is left to do in a situation like this?
How I can recover my acctuoal, initial account?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hi user! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! Are you sure the 24 recovery is correct? Try opening with another wallet like MyCrypto or MyEtherWallet. Metamask has the option of creating new accounts from the same seed, try adding several. Also how did you create the 24 words, usually metamask are 12, perhaps they were generated by a different wallet?

Answer (score 0):

Your address is Stuck in diversion path some where you have to recover it if you have balance so you can use iancolman
You can comment if you can't find it i will create another answer with whole information for you